# cannot find time module when changed sys.modules[__name__]

Tags: python

I modified `sys.modules[__name__]` to a class `Hello`, like this:

```
# hello.py
import sys
import time

class Hello:

    def print_time(self):
        print 'hello, current time is:', time.time()

sys.modules[__name__] = Hello()
```

Then, I imported `hello.py` in another python file `test.py` like:

```
# test.py
import hello
hello.print_time()
```

But, I got an error said `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'time'"` when I run `python test.py`.
It seemed that `hello.py` could not import the `time` module.

I really didn't figure out the problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have no explanation for why this happens and now I’m curious too, but to work around it you can abuse defaulting by changing `def print_time(self):` to `def print_time(self, time=time):`. I recall this used to be a common trick before Python supported lexical scoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the module <strike>`time`</strike> `hello` no longer has any references pointing to it, it got garbage-collected. Which means you lose your globals.

A slightly terrible fix: attach it to the class `Hello`.

```
import sys

class Hello:

    import time #Yes, the import statement in the class.

    def print_time(self):
        print 'hello, current time is:', time.time()

sys.modules[__name__] = Hello()
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out NightShadeQueen is right that the problem is that the original module object is being garbage-collected—but the question remained, why does it have that behavior? Namely, it still has a record of what globals *did* exist—referencing something that was *never* imported gives you a `NameError`, whereas everything that *did* exist is now `None`. I dug into the source to find out.

A module is an object. Like many objects, it has a `__dict__`, storing all attributes that do not have explicit slots. When you create global objects, they are added to this dictionary.

When a function is created, it maintains a reference to the globals dictionary at the time of definition. It does *not* maintain a reference to the module that owns that dictionary—it maintains a reference to the dictionary itself only.

For some reason, the finalizer of modules clears out its dictionary. (See [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/514f5d610175/Objects/moduleobject.c#l99).) Rather than deleting the keys wholesale, it replaces them all with `None`, a comment explaining that it avoids rehashing the dictionary.

Frankly, I don’t see why the module finalizer needs to do that; it could reasonably just remove its reference to the dictionary and let the dictionary deal with removing references to its values.